# GitHub through git between server and local pc

Tags: git, web, github, server, debian

I am running a Debian 9 server with my website on it,
I am using git with a bare repo and a local one on my pc, in order to code through vscode.
But I would like to see all the commits etc on GitHub, also because I share it with my classmates more easily
if is there a way would somebody explain it to me?
thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+multiple+remotes

Comment: Thank you, but in these ways would be all linked between the commits or is just the "double push* solution?

Comment: You push the same commits and references (branches and tags) to 2 repositories. Commits are independent from repositories.

Comment: @phd thank you very much!!